# Double read from socket

Tags: sockets, go

Go version: `go1.14.4 darwin/amd64`

**TCP server**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "time"
)

const (
    maxBufLen int = 4 * 1024
)

type Server struct {
}

func (s *Server) Start() {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:9001")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var connections []net.Conn
    defer func() {
        for _, conn := range connections {
            // ignore
            _ = conn.Close()
        }
    }()

    // loop...
    for {
        connected, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            if ne, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
                // temporary err will bi ignored
                continue
            } else {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
        }

        go handleConn(connected, true)

        connections = append(connections, connected)
    }
}

func handleConn(conn net.Conn, server bool) {
    buf := make([]byte, maxBufLen)

    for {
        // read
        setTimeout(conn)
        _, err := conn.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if ne, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && (ne.Timeout() || ne.Temporary()) {
                fmt.Println("need continue...")
                continue
            }

            if err == io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("EOF")
                break
            }

            // other...
            panic(err)
        }

        // handle recv msg.
        s := string(buf)
        if server {
            //fmt.Println("server recv req ", s)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("client recv resp ", s)
        }

        if server {
            output := "hi " + s
            ob := []byte(output)
            _, err := conn.Write(ob)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func setTimeout(conn net.Conn) {
    setErr := conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(20 * time.Second))
    if setErr != nil {
        panic(setErr)
    }
}
```

**TCP client**

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "time"
)

type Client struct {
    Exit chan struct{}
}

func (c *Client) Start() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9001")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    go handleWrite(conn)
    go handleConn(conn, false)

    <-c.Exit
}

func handleWrite(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        input := "carryxyh"
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte(input))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        <-time.After(100 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

**Main function**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

type Starter interface {
    Start()
}

func main() {
    var s Server
    var c Client

    go s.Start()
    go c.Start()

    sigs := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-sigs

    c.Exit <- struct{}{}

    fmt.Println("exit")
}
```

Running `package main` will print :

```
client recv resp  hi carryxyh
client recv resp  carryxyh
```

Printed twice. But from the program point of view, the server only writes information to the client once, and the content of the information should be `hi carryxyh`. But the client printed `carryxyh` in addition to `hi carryxyh`, which made me very confused.

During the investigation, I accidentally modified a line of code, and the program immediately returned to normal:

[modeifycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjDlz.png)

As shown above, I modified the server response information: `output := "hi "+ s` => `output := "hi "`, at this time the program only prints `client recv resp hi`.

This makes me completely confused, can anyone help me solve this problem? It would be better if there is a troubleshooting idea.

Comment: Use the length returned from `_, err := conn.Read(buf)`.  You are seeing data from the previous read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. But my confusion is why `fmt.Println("client recv resp ", s)` is triggered twice.
When I use `output := "hi "`, it will only be triggered once.

Or, can you give me more information to describe it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This seems to be very effective.

But I don't understand why I don't pay attention to the returned length, which will cause conn.Read to be triggered twice. It would be great if you could give me an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ6N3.png)

这里你忽略了读取的字节长度，可能返回0字节，你又把buf的内容 又回写给client了.
_, err := conn.Read(buf) 改成 bytesRead, err := conn.Read(buf)   ;
if bytesRead <= 0 { // 没有buf 可以读取 }

--
eg:

if bytesRead == 0 && err == nil {
err = io.EOF
log.Errorf("[network] ReadOnce maybe always return (0, nil) and causes dead loop, Connection = %d, Local Address = %+v, Remote Address = %+v",
c.id, c.rawConnection.LocalAddr(), c.RemoteAddr())
}